# "The server refused the connection" error in Facebook App

Tags: https

I am working on creating a facebook app for a Magento store and listing products in facebook app.

My site is not HTTPS, but facebook app requires HTTPS, it showed *"Operation timed out"* error. So I disabled secured browsing option in facebook and tested in facebook appcentre. After disabled secured browsing, the site was worked well till yesterday. But today, I tried to check the output, It showing this error *"The server refused the connection"*, even I disabled the secured browsing already.

How can I fix this error? Please look at the screenshot for clarification.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My server is not https, but the facebook apps require https.

I think you gave the answer yourself.

Try setting up your server with HTTPS before trying anything else.